# using Linq to query XDocument keeps throwing Null pointer exception

Tags: linq-to-xml

How do I use Linq to query an xml doc? When I use the code below the "where" clause is throwing "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". Specifically, I think the node is null. Please help!

My xml looks like this:

```
<qbo:QboCompanyPreferences xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:qbp="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbopayroll/v1" xmlns:qbo="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo">
  <qbo:Preference>
    <Name>TaxAccountId</Name>
    <Value>34</Value>
  </qbo:Preference>
  <qbo:Preference>
    <Name>TaxPercent</Name>
    <Value>4.5%</Value>
  </qbo:Preference>
</qbo:QboCompanyPreferences>
```

I'm using XDocument like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(serviceResponse);
string taxNodeName = "TaxPercent";
XNamespace qbo = "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo";

var Preference = (from node in doc.Descendants(qbo + "Preference")
                        where node.Element("Name").Value == taxNodeName
                        select node).FirstOrDefault();

Response.Write(Preference.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be handled already but try this

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(serviceResponse);
string taxNodeName = "TaxPercent";
XNamespace qbo = "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo";
XNamespace ns = "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2";

var Preference = (from node in doc.Descendants(qbo + "Preference")
                    where node.Element(ns+"Name").Value == taxNodeName
                    select node).FirstOrDefault();

Response.Write(Preference.ToString());
```

The node was not null, but the Element was not found and so `.Value` was called on `null`.